How to find slope of tangents at points where two or more tangents can be drawn to the graph.
There are some graph which crosses itself and at those points where they cross themselves, we can draw two or more tangents. From my understanding of differentiability, I guess that we can wrap up those cases just saying that derivative does not exist at that point, but sometimes we need to find the slope of those tangents, for example if we want to find the radii of curvatures. As an example, we may think of $x^3 + y^3 = 3axy$, whose graph looks like this:

Now if we want to know the radii of curvatures at origin, according to formula $\frac{(1 + y_1 ^ 2)^\frac{3}{2}}{y_2}$, we need to find the $y_1$ and $y_2$.
If we differentiate the equation, we get
$$3x^2 + 3y^2y_1 = 3axy_1 + 3ay$$
So, $$y_1 = \frac {ay - x^2}{y^2 - ax}$$
But if we put $(0,0)$ here, both the numerator and denominator become zero, so we cannot say certainly whether the slope is zero or undefined. If we evaluate limit of the first derivative when x and y both tends to zero, we will get undefined or infinity if we approach along y axis and we will get zero if we approach along x axis.
Is this a rigorous process to find the slopes? If yes, then how will I know along which line I have to evaluate the limits? Is there any other better process for handling these cases?
Thanks for reading the long question patiently.

"$y_1$" and "$y_2$" are NOT commonly used notations for the first and second derivative. Most commonly, these notations are used to indicate two particular values of the $y$ variable. So you just throwing them into your post without even a word of introduction makes your post highly confusing. The common notations for first and second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ are $y'$ and $y''$ (per Newton) or $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ (per Leibnitz). $y^{(1)}$ and $y^{(2)}$ are also used when even higher derivatives are also in discussion.

As for your problem, note how I did not just say "the derivative", but rather "the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$". This is the core of your issue. Derivatives are rates of change of one well-defined variable with respect to another variable. In order to talk about them, one must specify which variable is being differentiated, and with respect to which other variable. Further the variable being differentiated must be a well-defined function of the other variable at the point of differentiation. $x^3 + y^3 = 3axy$ does not establish $y$ as a well defined function of $x$ about $(0,0)$

The problem here is not that the tangents are undefinable. They are well defined, but there are two separate tangents at $(0,0)$, and the implicit function formula $x^3 + y^3=3axy$ has to cover both of them, which it cannot do. It is implicit differentation that breaks down here, not the concept of tangents to the curve. A second problem is that the formula you are trying to use for radius of curvature only applies when $y$ is established as a function of $x$. So it doesn't apply to the second tangent at $(0,0)$. And thirdly, what is the "radius of curvature" of a straight line?
